# Are there any tools to automatically correct math formulas?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, editing, user-scripts

I am a person who prefer standard formula, so I often edit the formula to make it look better. But I find most of the mistakes or malformedTeX writing have repeated pattern. For example: `sin` to `\sin` ,`cos` to `\cos` . So is there a tool to help achieve this goal?

Comment: How is the tool supposed to know that you mean $\sin$ and not $sin$ (which is equal to $nsi$)?

Comment: Aren't there IDEs which would do this better; it could alert you to possible issues while you are typing? (I haven't used a LaTeX IDE, but I'm assuming some of them do this!)

Answer (score 14):

I wrote [this Python script](https://github.com/wuyudi/SE-Editor-Helper) to make life easier. The *stable* version is v0.4

> This script is far from prefect, so maybe you will meet many kinds of problems. (Because it's for my personal usage.)

Effect:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
2. double click the script
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

> just now I remove the `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

Comment: Idk if you normally type latex like this, but I suggest using newlines inside complicated equations. It can help make it easier to read.